# Is the Gödel universe Wick rotatable?

Tags: complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry, obstruction-theory

Take Wick rotatability being as the way defined in the following article by Helleland and Hervik:

- Christer Helleland, Sigbjørn Hervik, *Wick rotations and real GIT*, Journal of Geometry and Physics **123** (2018) 343–361, doi:[j.geomphys.2017.09.009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.geomphys.2017.09.009), [arXiv:1703.04576](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04576)

Is the [Gödel universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric) ***globally and smoothly*** Wick rotatable according to this definition?

Comment: Note for logicians: The Gödel universe mentioned here is not  Gödel's constructible universe $L$, but rather his model of the Einstein equations in physics, and GIT does not refer to the Gödel incompleteness theorem, but to geometric invariant theory.

Comment: Now I want to read a Greg Egan novel where scientists discover at the same time that we live in Gödel relativistic universe and that our sets are in L.

Comment: Hi @PseudoNeo, I think that if we lived in an "only slightly perturbed universe", as that you propose, our (idealized) brains would be well modeled by neural networks, thus have the computational power of TMs. Other dynamics too. All usual formal systems would be mutually representable -computationally equivalent to TMs. We could use the same mathematical theories and would need only very weak ones to do physics; customary foundations would be as debatable as here because Gödel's 2nd theorem would still hold, physics would not help discriminate, and our sociology would probably pick only ZFC.

Comment: Is this me who feels schizophrenic outta these comments or sth worse?

Comment: Closely related crosspost: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798544/ (it is considered good practice to mention this in your question to avoid duplicate work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Clearly, as Robert Bryant [indicates](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462961/2383), it is Wick-rotatable to a different Lorentzian space. However, it is also Wick-rotatable to a Riemannian space, albeit *negative definite* space. In our paper these are considered equivalent due to the anti-symmetry $g\mapsto -g$.

The key here is to realise that the 3-dim space $z=\mathrm{constant}$ restricts to a Lorentzian metric on $\SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Explicitly, first we do the coordinate changes $x=-\ln X$, $y=\sqrt{2}Y$, to transform the Gödel metric to:
$$ g=\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\left(-\left(dt+\frac{\sqrt{2}dY}{X}\right)^2+\frac{1}{X^2}(dX^2+dY^2)+dz^2\right). $$
This is one of the standard forms of a metric on the LRS $\SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ space. I can't remember the the explicit coordinate transformation but this can again be rewritten (up to determining some appropriate constants $a,b$):
$$ g=\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\left[-\left(dt+a\sinh(x_1)d x_2\right)^2+b^2((dx_1)^2+\cosh^2(x_1)(dx_2)^2)+dz^2\right]. $$
Now, the Wick rotation $(t,x_1,x_2,z)\mapsto (t,ix_1,ix_2,iz)$ turns it into:
$$ g=\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\left[-\left(dt-a\sin(x_1)d x_2\right)^2-b^2((dx_1)^2+\cos^2(x_1)(dx_2)^2)-dz^2\right]. $$
Note that this is the negative-definite version of a (Berger sphere)${}\times \mathbb{R}$, which indeed has 5 Killing vectors, same as Gödel.

Comment: What does it mean for a Riemannian metric to be negative definite? I thought Riemannian metrics are by definition positive definite, aren't they?

Comment: Sure, usually we define the Riemannian metric to be positive definite. But we could as well defined it to be negative-definite. This is just a convention. Especially, in Lorentizian geometry, both sign conventions are common: (+---) or (-+++). In neutral signature this is even more mixed up as they are (--++) or (++--). In any case, considering Wick rotations as we did in the paper, they are considered identical as they may be mixed up under a Wick rotation anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Well I would ageee with you that the problem can be reduced to a matter of convention, if only there did not exist any positive-definite Riemannian slice. But if there exists at least one, then one faces the problem another way around and cannot escape from it. Do you think it's possible to prove such argument?

Comment: Moreover, along with my personal reason of interest in your article, I want to know why exactly (in each chosen and fixed frame of reference), time can not be complexified to result in a sign-definite(so to speak) Riemannian geometry, and apart from time (if at all!) also space should be complexified. What is exactly the nature of the obstruction for time to do the job alone? Is it geometric or topologic and manifests through geometry? To my guess the topological mismatch between the Alexandrov topology and the manifold topology might have some role though it's merely a guess.

Comment: If you consider a specific observer following a worldline with proper time t, then you'd get directly constraints on the metric functions. In particular, if the worldlines are non-twisting, you can foliate using the proper time t. Then again, if the metric is symmetric under the time-reversion, t--> -t, then it seems to be possible to Wick-rotate \tau=it.

Comment: But such foliation does not exist in case of the Gödel metric as there're CTCs involved. The point of my question is rather of global interest. Of course you define Wick Rotatability in a local fashion but I'm concerned with global and smooth Wick rotation. I'm afraid that there might exist an obstruction in passing from local to global. I also need some clarification about what you mathematically mean by twisting worldlines. Thanks

Comment: By non-twisting world-lines i mean a congruence of vector fields (or rather its corresponding 1-form) u for which u_{a;b}-u_{b;a}=0. Using exterior derivative: du=0. So that u is surface-forming. 
The global question is harder, and certainly our approach was local.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151365/discussion-between-bastam-tajik-and-sigbjorn-hervik).

Comment: I'd be thankful if you could contribute also to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/456763/503363

Comment: Can a Lorentzian singularity be regularized under Wick rotation to a Riemannian manifold? Is a topological mismatch between the Alexandrov topology and manifold topology necessary for that matter?Of course I am assuming to Wick rotate locally as presumably topological mismatch acts as a topological obstruction to global Wick rotation.

Answer (score 8):

I may be misreading the sources that you list for the definition of *Wick-rotatable*, but, I believe that the following construction does fit that definition:  According to the Wikipedia page that the OP cites, the Gödel metric can be written on $\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$ in the form
$$
g = \frac1{2\omega^2}\left(-(\mathrm{d}t+ e^x\,\mathrm{d}y)^2+\mathrm{d}x^2 + \tfrac12(e^x\,\mathrm{d}y)^2+\mathrm{d}z^2\right).
$$
Then writing $t=i\,\tau$ and $y = i\,\eta$, one gets a globally and smoothly Wick-rotated Lorentzian metric
$$
\tilde g = \frac1{2\omega^2}\left((\mathrm{d}\tau+ e^x\,\mathrm{d}\eta)^2+\mathrm{d}x^2 - \tfrac12(e^x\,\mathrm{d}\eta)^2+\mathrm{d}z^2\right).
$$
on $\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates $(\tau,x,\eta,z)$.

Note that the source cited does not require that one of the Wick-related metrics be positive definite.  Perhaps more computation could determine whether there is a positive definite Wick-rotation of Gödel's metric.

Comment: Right. But at the very least, one can say in this case not only time but also space needs to be complexified. Right?

Comment: @BastamTajik: Yes, but, remember that in the paper that you cite, the authors complexify *everything* in the sense that they first extend the metric to a holomorphic metric on $\mathbb{C}^4$ and then consider 'real slices' of dimension 4.

Comment: True. Now I'm thinking of how to limit the paper approach to complex time and real space. Also your point on the positive definitness of the metric is quite pertinent. I'm super curious. Thanks

Comment: @BastamTajik:  Note, however, that the whole point of Lorentzian geometry is that there is no natural separation of time and space.  As Minkowski famously said, "Henceforth, space by itself, and time by itself, are doomed to fade away into mere shadows, and only a kind of union of the two will preserve an independent reality."

Comment: Yes actually I noted this. The only question left for me for the moment is the positive-definitness of the Wick rotated metric.

Comment: And what if I search for a Riemannian slice instead of Pseudo-Riemannian?

Comment: @BastamTajik:  There is a way to search for the Riemannian slices and determine whether any exist, but it requires a computation that I don't have time to do right now.

Comment: Can you please refer to some resources that give an idea of the computation? Thanks

Comment: @BastamTajik:  If you look at my answer to the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165304/obtain-lorentzian-manifolds-from-riemannian-ones-by-wick-rotation, you will see how I describe the approach.  There is an $n$-plane field $H$ on the bundle $\pi:R\to M^\mathbb{C}$ whose integrals are the real slices.  You have to compute $H$ and then determine the $n$-dimensional integral manifolds of $H$.  I explain the results in the case $n=2$, but one needs to do it for $n=4$ in the Gödel case.  This will give the answer; it's a finite computation, but not short.

Comment: Anyway the rotation you have proposed here does not lead to a Riemannian manifold. I should search if there exists any! Still thanks!